# Who is Krsanu in the Rig Veda?

Tags: vishnu, rig-veda

In the [Rig Veda, 1.155.2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01155.htm) it’s written

> yā martyāya pratidhīyamānamit kṛśānorasturasanāmuruṣyathaḥ ||

> That which hath been directed well at mortal man, bow-armed **Kṛśānu**'s
> arrow, ye turn far aside.

Who is Krsanu?

Comment: Krsanu means generally refers to Agni. In the context specifically asked I don’t know whether it carries the same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Rig Veda IV.27.3-4](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv04027.htm) and also at IX.77.2, the archer Kr̥śānu was mentioned as guardian of Soma.

The archer Kr̥śānu,guardian of Soma, shoots at the fleeing falcon with his precious cargo, and manages only to shoot off one feather.

> ava yac chyeno asvanīd adha dyor vi yad yadi vāta ūhuḥ puraṃdhim |
> sṛjad yad asmā ava ha kṣipaj jyāṃ kṛśānur astā manasā bhuraṇyan ||
>
> ṛjipya īm indrāvato na bhujyuṃ śyeno jabhāra bṛhato adhi ṣṇoḥ | antaḥ
> patat patatry asya parṇam adha yāmani prasitasya tad veḥ ||
>
> When the falcon then roared down from heaven, when—or if—they carried
> Plenitude away from there, when the ***archer Kr̥śānu***, alert in mind,
> released and let fly his bow-string down toward him,
>
> Flying straight, the falcon brought him to the companions of Indra
> from the lofty back (of heaven), just as (the Aśvins brought) Bhujyu
> (home, with their birds). **A feather *of the winged one, of the bird
> launched then on its course, flew between (heaven and earth)**.

Answer (score 1):

Krsanu is most probably an asura of drought.

> Krsanu: Guardian of Soma, most probably Asura of drought who prevents
> men from enjoying life giving rain.

**Rig Veda Samhita Bengali translation by Professor Nilanjana Sikdardutta, Ramakrishna Mission Institute of Culture**